# Reel in anchor using physics

Tags: animation, physics

I want to animate an anchor being pulled in by a motor on the boat. The anchor is attached to some chains. I am having trouble with the physics. I am using the built in physics system, not the Blender Game Engine. On the boat I have a motor that is turning. Is is attached to the chain which is attached to the anchor. **How can I use physics to animate the reeling in of an anchor?**

[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27039)

The motor

[image]

The anchor

[image]

my attempt so far:

as you can see it's not working like it should.

http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=67306

Comment: I can't test now, but it looks like you are not using *Mesh* collision for the chain links, which is necessary for concave shapes. I would actually recommend using *constraints* instead, and disable collisions between linked links. I'll add an answer as soon as I can..

Comment: Mesh collision can be one of the problem. But there seem to be other problems however in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several issues with your file:

- The object origins are not centered. The origins are used to calculate the center of mass, which means that they can result in strange behavior if they are not correctly centered. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> Origin to center of mass* to snap the origin to the center of mass.
- The intersecting concave links are using the *Convex Hull* collision shape. Because the hole in the middle of each link is a concave shape, the links then collide and fly apart. To the simulator it appears as if the links are inside one another.
  However, note for a chain I recommend using *[Constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/constraints/introduction.html)* instead.
- Some objects have unapplied transforms. In many cases applying the scale and rotation can improve the stability and behavior of a simulation. Just beware when applying transforms to animated objects.
- *[Animated](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties.html)* is not enabled on the capstan. Enabling this is important if you want to control rigid bodies with the animation system.

## Setting up *[Constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/constraints/introduction.html)* for a chain:

1. Select all the links in the chain.
2. Press *Connect* in *3D View > Tool Shelf > Physics > Rigid body tools*, then set the constraint type to *Point* (sort of a ball joint) and the *Connection Pattern* to *Chain by distance*:

   [image]

By default the new constraints (added to the empties) will have *Disable collisions* enabled which disables collisions between objects constrained to each other. I recommend leaving this setting on, and keeping the collision shape on *Convex Hull* as nothing besides the links themselves are likely to try and pass through the hole.

[image]

[image] (For Blender 2.8)

Comment: The blend files are not available - death links. Too bad. The solution from gandalf3 looks like a really great anchor/chain example.

Comment: @user1209926 Thanks for letting me know, I've re-made the example in Blender 2.8. In general I have copies of all the .blends I've uploaded so please don't hesitate to ask (this was an exception since it was actually a modified version of the .blend from the OP)