# Rigid Body breaking links of chain

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have made some chain links. I used the Rigid Body Tools and made the two end links passive and the others active. They are all set to shape Mesh. I've tried setting the weight to acrylic, cardboard, etc to lessen the pull they have when falling. How do I prevent these links from coming apart? I've even tried scaling up the scene but that also doesn't work.

Peter

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Try using constraints. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7280/599

Comment: What about then still having the links collide? I disabled No Collision on all the empties and made the links object type mesh and still they all slink into a strand

Comment: @gandalf3 Looked at your other post on someone doing a similar thing but it doesn't solve the situation

Comment: Works [just fine](http://gfycat.com/HardtofindFemaleFlickertailsquirrel) for me.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: @gandalf3 I seem to have fixed it. I had to individually select each constraint link after hiding the meshes and deselect No Collision. Do you know how I can do this without manually selecting each one? It didn't want me to do it in bulk.

Here is my .blend anyways http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33389

Comment: Select all the empties (Box select `B` and Circle select `C` can be useful here), then disable *no collision* and right click on the (now disabled) checkbox and press *Copy to selected*.

Comment: 2835: It's better to use (Select / Select pattern../ Constr* )  to select all the empties. And then yes, use needed value's "Copy to selected" (from active) command.

Answer (score 6):

From Blender 2.91, there is now a *"compound parent"* shape option dedicated to this kind of shape (with concavities):

[image]

You can find its description from the [release page here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/Physics).

And [in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties/collisions.html?highlight=compound%20parent#collisions):

> Compound Parent
>
> Takes the collision shapes from the object’s children and combines
> them.
>
> This makes it possible to create concave shapes from primitive shapes.
>
> This usually results in a faster simulation than the Mesh collision
> shape while also being generally more stable.

The file below is the demo from David Vogel (all credits to him):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lemon dl'd this to potentially answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238085/hanging-chain-help-up-by-two-ends in the end no matter what I tried could not make other end also animated, (to hang from both or hang from swapped end)

Comment: I downloaded the compound parent project (I am having similar issues to the OP). If I delete and re-bake the Rigid Body Physics, the chains fly apart. This is touching NOTHING else in the project. Is this broken in 3.4.1?

Answer (score 3):

You need to raise the accuracy of your simulation, by changing the *Steps Per Second* and *Solver Iterations* in the scene panel:

[image]

Raise those to values.

Also, in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVYYMG3QVY#t=363), it is recommended to change the mass of your objects.

**Note:**

This will influence simulation times

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix: do not use type *Passive*, instead use type *Active* without *Dynamic*. I think Blender simulation will skip too much stuff with *Passive* objects and as a result, active objects can pass through those pretty easily if force gets high enough.

When you set type to *Active* the simulation gets more accurate and disabling the *Dynamic* feature, the object still stays unmovable similar to *Passive*.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
When I set the origin to top link in order to rotate the chain,
I just needed to set the origin to geometry for all the links after finishing with the rotation...
easy to miss