# Problem simulating rigid bodies for chains with compound shapes

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I've been trying this example from David here with compound shapes to create chains. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203405/66925

If I open the file, it works. But if I delete the bake and try to simulate it myself it all breaks apart. This is in Blender 2.92. Anyone know what's wrong? This is the same for my own simulations pretty much.