# Hanging chain help up by two ends

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to find a way to have this following chain be an object influenced by gravity.

[image]

The two pieces of chain on either side are fixed and will not by affected y gravity and can be moved around using armature. I want the rest of the chain to respond accordingly but the individual chains pieces not to be deformed

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I have done something similar once, just rigid bodies, separate chain into individual links, take two pieces you want to be not affected and make them passive rigid bodies with passive attribute, change rest to active attribute... don't forget to give them Mesh and not convex hull and you are good to go, use some more settings to make it look better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I have said in the comment, make your chain by links, select them all and join them together. Go to Physics and give this object Rigid body physics. Use these settings:
[image]

just make it active and change the convex hull to mesh... you can tweak mass later to give it better results...

After that go to edit mode, select all vertices, use RMB and select Separate -> by Loose parts... After this, your chain links are separated pieces and you need to select all of them, use RMB and select Set origin -> Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)... After this select two sides links and change those and only those 2 to passive in their physics settings.

Check the Animated option and you can freely move your chain however you wish(just don't move it too fast)

[image]
[image]

Note: This is just a base for your problem, you will need to set Surface response, Sensitivity, mass, gravity and other things based on what you want to get as result.

Comment: I've tried this, but whenever I run the animation, the links just 'explode' for lack of a better word. All the links go crazy and start flying off in different directions

Comment: that happens if origins are not in middle, if you use convex hull instead of mesh or use too small links with too big serface sensitivity, can You show me your chain so I can see where is mistake?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20970/rigid-body-breaking-links-of-chain/203405#203405

Comment: @MikoCG, your comment about the origins and using lower surface sensitiviy seemed to stop it from exploding, but the chain still breaks after the animation is played. Link to my setup: https://imgur.com/a/NspflFc

Comment: Actually, never mind, I just set up contransints and that seemed to do the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: On second thought, would it be possible to animate the end links on top of the rigid bodies and contraints? If so, how? Because right now, when I move either link on the end, the rest of the chain just follows the original animation