# What is happening to Suzanne's eyes during this use of the Boolean modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So, I used a Boolean modifier on Suzanne and a fairly default cylinder. The results, as they move along, go something like this:  [video](http://tinypic.com/r/2vkn6lv/8).

The modifier is set to union.  As you can see, something strange is happening: only her eyes appear.  I did do some interesting things with it previously using the subsurface modifier - but that time, her eyes dissapeared, as opposed to the rest of her head!

Kudos to anyone who can help me with this.

Comment: The eyes are not connected to the default Suzanne, resulting in a [non-manifold mesh](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7280/599). This makes things tricky for boolean operations.

Comment: Hmm... how did I make it so only her eyes dissapeared?

Comment: Well, it results in kind of undefined behavior. So it's unpredictable.

Comment: Edit Mode - Select non-Manifold - F, then it works well with booleans.

Answer (score 6):

You are using a non manifold mesh. Basicly, non manifold means, in layman's terms, not water tight.

Here is an example:

[image]

The cube has a hole in it. In Suzanne's case, its the fact that her eyes aren't attached to her head.

Here is a quick way to fix Suzanne:

[image]

Note: I use the loop tools add-on accessed by <kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: Note that blender has a bridge tool built in which AFAIK can do everything the loop tools version can.