# chain "breaks" when animation starts

Tags: animation

i have this blender file and i am trying to make a chain with is stucked in the ceiling so the first chain link is passive, all others are active.
Unfortunately the second chain is "breaking" out the passive one and i have no idea why it happens and how to fix it.
Can anybody give me an advise?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Also related: [Reel in anchor using physics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/reel-in-anchor-using-physics)

Comment: thank you...i 'll try that!!

Comment: Maybe this is working in 2.91 with shape set as "compound parent" Have a look at the relase note here https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/Physics

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, is duplicate meaning this is not working in 2.91 either? (I've not tested it myself, except testing the example file provided on blender.org which seems to be fine)

Comment: What's not working? As far as I've tested the solution in the answer works in 2.91

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I mean there is now a specialized shape type in 2.91.

Comment: That seems to be an additional solution for newer versions besides the one described. You could post a new answer describing it if you like. Feel free to ping me if you do I'd upvote

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, did it. I think there is enough information.