# Why chain object break when colliding with another object?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I create chain object and i apply rigid body simulation in it. After that, i try the chain and the chain fall likes real chain like in this picture [image] but when i try it in different position, the chain break just like this [image]

I have tried using constraint, but the chain still will breaks, be it whole or some part of chain.

What is the problem? Here is my blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/4e5bebdcaedd46d8a20fb23d6c399993

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In 3.0** it seems to work: Apply the scale + rotation of the links, set the origins to geometry, add some edge loops, and it will work fine. You can also tweak the *Substeps Per Frame* and *Solver Iterations* values in the *Scene > Rigid Body World* panel:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems buggy in **2.7** so what you can do is first apply the transforms, set the origin to geometry and edit the geometry, then use [**this answer**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/reel-in-anchor-using-physics) by Gandalf: Select 2 adjacent links, go into the left panel > *Physics > Rigid Body Tools > Constraints >* click on *Connect*. It will create an empty between the 2 links. Select the empty and in the *Properties panel > Physics > Rigid Body Constraint*, choose *Type > Point* and uncheck the *Disable Collisions* option. Select the 2 next links and do the same until the bottom. In order to avoid shakings, go into the *Properties panel > Scene > Rigid Body World*, increase the *Solver Iterations* up to 10:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135524/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-why-chain-object-break-when-colliding-with-ano).