# How to make a chain look like it's hanging naturally?

Tags: modifiers, physics, collision

I made a single chainlink then used an Array Modifier to duplicate with object offset linked to rotated "plain axes" object to rotate alternating links. I made a single link to be the anchor point at the top of the chain but I'm having trouble with the collision. I'm newish to Blender so I'm not sure if a collision is what I'm looking for. I tried combinations of collision and rigid body but the main chain isn't interacting with the anchor link so it just passes through it. I want each link to fall and hang on the preceding link, with the exception of the anchor link not moving at all.

I'm not trying to create an animation; I'm just looking for a visual representation image of the end-product.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried active and passive rigid bodies?

Comment: that worked but not for the anchor link

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I realized it doesn’t take into account that you’ve got the whole chain as an array. That won’t work. It’s still the same single object, so they will all move together. They need to be separate rigid bodies. Also, why is the first link green? Is that just a material difference, or is it possible that it’s normals are inverted or something else that could mess up a rigid body simulation?

Comment: @TheLabCat I think you're on a good track; to convert the links to individual objects the OP could apply the array modifier and then use *`P` > By Loose Parts* in edit mode to separate the links. Here's an (old) related answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7286/599

Answer (score 3):

Some things that you need to do:

- The *Physics > Collision* is not useful in your case (it is in case you want your object to interact with *Cloth* or *Soft Body*).
- Choose *Collisions > Shape > Mesh* instead of *Convex Hull* for both the top link and the rest of the chain, otherwise the holes of these objects won't be considered.
- Apply the *Array* modifier and make each link a separate object if they are supposed to be simulated as well.
- Put the origin at the geometry of each object.
- Scale up the objects, it looks like increasing the scale make the calculation easier.
- Apply the transforms (*Scale* and *Rotation*).

To make an animation work correctly, there may be several tricks, I propose one in the second part of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMwDqlRzJ4g) (in French).

Comment: Thanks! The links are now interacting with each other but not enough? When I begin the animation, only the first link hangs on to the anchor, the remaining seem to break off from the chain.

Comment: Could you please share your new file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=yywWbrJY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/yywWbrJY/)

Comment: scaling up does seem to help but it still breaks eventually. also how come the links keep shaking after they've fallen.

Comment: I've already tried to give rigid body to a chain and was enable to achieve something good (links were exploding, shaking, etc), maybe someone will explain how to do it but I suspect you need to fake with some trick, like the one I explain in the linked video, or maybe check this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjVhS0TyyX8

Comment: You could also try the Connect constraint, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/reel-in-anchor-using-physics

Comment: i see, okay well thanks for helping!

Comment: i was looking at the anvil page earlier but constraints were confusing me. I'm still very early in my blender journey but I think that's what I'm tackling next

Comment: it's a rigid body constraint, but I'm not sure that it will work much better than rigid body, you probably need to use a trick like the one i describe: the chain is kind of attached to a cloth simulation. But the best solution also depends on your final goals, what is your storyboard, etc

Comment: I forgot that you didn't want an animation, what is the final image (end product as you say) you wanted?

Comment: I just want a chain to hang naturally, which I don't think I need this much detail/effort for. I am also trying to learn more about blender by figuring out how to achieve these things that I'm finding difficult.

Comment: If you just need a chain hanging, it's easy to do with an Array modifier

Comment: Yes, but what i want to account for is (1) the links hanging off eachother so the distance between them is perceptually zero and (2) natural deviations in the angle/rotation of each link so that they're not perfectly stacked. the part im finding challenging is how to make this happen computationally [without manually adjusting each link].